# libusb can't find a specific device connected to computer

Tags: python, usb, avr, libusb

I'm trying to run a python code to control AVR ATmega32u4 and then, turn on and turn off the LEDs connected to it. For that, I got LUFA firmware, compiled the .c files and burnt it to m32u4. The VID is 03EB and PID is 204F, but I can't find it with libusb (is not listed), and so I can't run the python code because it doesn't find the usb device. How can I solve this issue?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Welcome to SO, [please check how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a snip code and more details to get help.